# how to access DLLs when published using produce single file

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, .net-core-publishsinglefile

I have a .net 7 console application which I want to distribute as a single file for future updates and automatic updates.

I have used options provided in the VS publish settings as attached image.

[image]

It produces single file but I want to access the DLLs and classes inside those DLLs which was accessible when the file was produced using Costura.Fody but not in this new output.

ILSpy shows the list of assemblies but when we use `GetManifestResourceNames` method, it does not return the list of DLLs in the bundle.

Comment: What do you mean by "access the DLLs and classes", and why would you need to do this?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/45309

Comment: @AndyVaal there are certain tasks that are part of the referenced DLLs/packages which I need to access and create a list as command line tasks so I need to scan all the available Tasks in there